# python pandas read_excel problem reading zeros in the left number

Tags: python, pandas

with the solutions that online I can't solve the problem:

original file:

```
           CODE     QUANTITY   PRICE
1        032040014        32   15.60
2        032039012         5   12.30
3        023703010        10   17.80
```

```
file_ = pandas.read_excel(file_name, dtype={"CODE":str})
```

read_file:

```
           CODE     QUANTITY   PRICE
1        32040014        32   15.60
2        32039012         5   12.30
3        23703010        10   17.80
```

help please!?

Comment: you're making CODE a str, hence 0 is the suffix. try to make it an *int*

Comment: Try to [set the dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html): `pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', dtype={'Oct':object})`

Comment: @Naveed IIUC the problem is that 'CODE' is being casted to int, but the OP wants to keep the 0 at the beginning, that's part of the code.

Comment: Your code works for me. Check that your excel contains that 0 before the number, and it is not really a number that shows a 0 before because of some weird cell format.

Comment: yes the 0s are present in the excel file, but opening the excel from python they are not read, either if I read the column as a string or as an integer

Comment: are there any other solutions?